# Generic A*-Algorithm without clone

Tags: graph, rust, a-star

I wrote a generic implementation of A* with the focus of not having to clone nodes or actions. Thanks to some very good advice I received on Stack Overflow, I have arrived at the following final result:

### lib.rs

```
extern crate typed_arena;

use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::{BinaryHeap, HashMap};
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

use typed_arena::Arena;

/// Extension of SearchTree that features action cost
pub trait SearchTreeState<A>: Eq + Hash {
    /// Get a list of available actions for this tree state and their corresponding costs
    fn available_actions(&self) -> Vec<(A, f64)>;
    
    /// Apply an action previously returned by available_actions
    /// and return the new search tree state
    fn apply_action(&self, act: &A) -> Self;
}

/// Node in the expanded search tree for uniform cost search with heuristic
struct HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A> + Hash
{
    cost: f64,
    heuristic_cost: f64,
    parent_index: usize,
    action: Option<A>,
    tree: T,
}

impl<A, T> PartialEq for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A> + Hash
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &HucsNode<A, T>) -> bool {
        // Nodes are equal if their tree states as this is what we are
        // interested in when comparing them in the map
        return self.tree == other.tree
    }
}

impl<A, T> Eq for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A> + Hash
{
}

impl<A, T> Hash for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A> + Hash
{
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher
    {
        // Nodes are just hashed by their tree states since that also
        // defines their equality
        self.tree.hash(state);
    }
}

impl<A, T> PartialOrd for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A> + Hash
{
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &HucsNode<A, T>) -> Option<Ordering> {
        // Must never return None here as used by Ord
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl<A, T> Ord for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A> + Hash
{
    fn cmp(&self, other: &HucsNode<A, T>) -> Ordering {
        // Nodes are ordered by their summed costs for the open list
        let self_cost = self.cost + self.heuristic_cost;
        let other_cost = other.cost + other.heuristic_cost;
        
        // Flip for min-heap, PartialOrd should never return None
        return other_cost.partial_cmp(&self_cost).unwrap();
    }
}

/// A wrapper for a borrowed hashable thing
struct BackedHashWrapper<'a, T: 'a + Hash + Eq> {
    source: &'a T
}

impl<'a, T> Hash for BackedHashWrapper<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a + Eq + Hash
{
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher
    {
        self.source.hash(state);
    }
}

impl<'a, T> PartialEq for BackedHashWrapper<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a + Eq + Hash
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &BackedHashWrapper<T>) -> bool {
        self.source == other.source
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Eq for BackedHashWrapper<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a + Eq + Hash
{
}

/// The initial capacity of both the arena of old nodes and the hash map of old nodes
const INITIAL_OLD_LIST_CAPACITY: usize = 1_000_000;

/// Perform a uniform cost search with a valid heuristic function on a search tree.
/// Returns a sequence of actions if a state is found that satisfies the predicate or 
/// None if the search terminates beforehand.
pub fn hucs<A, T: SearchTreeState<A> + Hash> (
    tree: T,
    predicate: &Fn(&T) -> bool,
    heuristic: &Fn(&T) -> f64,
) -> Option<Vec<A>> {

    // Min heap of the nodes in the expanded tree, ordered by actual cost to get to node
    // + heuristic cost to goal
    let mut open_list = BinaryHeap::new();
    
    // Push the initial node onto the tree
    open_list.push(HucsNode {
        action: None,
        // Parent index of root should never be read
        parent_index: usize::max_value(),
        cost: 0.0,
        heuristic_cost: heuristic(&tree),
        tree: tree,
    });
    
    let mut found_leaf = None;
    
    let old_nodes_arena = Arena::with_capacity(INITIAL_OLD_LIST_CAPACITY);
    
    // Destroy hash_map after this scope so items in the arena are no longer immutably borrowed
    {
        // Contains hashes and references to old_nodes_arena
        let mut hash_map = HashMap::with_capacity(INITIAL_OLD_LIST_CAPACITY);
        let mut current_node_index = 0 as usize;
    
        'outer: while let Some(current_node) = open_list.pop() {
        
            if predicate(&current_node.tree) {
                found_leaf = Some(current_node);
                break 'outer;
            }
            
            // Temporarily wrap the current node so we can check against the hash map
            match hash_map.get(&BackedHashWrapper{ source: &current_node }) {
                // Skip if we already had a better or equal path to this state with less cost
                Some(old_cost) => if *old_cost <= current_node.cost { continue 'outer; },
                None           => {}
            }
            
            for (action, action_cost) in current_node.tree.available_actions() {
            
                let new_tree = current_node.tree.apply_action(&action);
                let new_cost = current_node.cost + action_cost;
                
                let new_node = HucsNode {
                    action: Some(action),
                    cost: new_cost,
                    parent_index: current_node_index,
                    heuristic_cost: heuristic(&new_tree),
                    tree: new_tree,
                };
                
                open_list.push(new_node);
            }
            
            // Add the current node to the arena of old nodes
            let current_node_ref = old_nodes_arena.alloc(current_node);
            
            // Add a wrapper to the hash map for the current node
            hash_map.insert(BackedHashWrapper {
                source: current_node_ref
            }, current_node_ref.cost);
            
            current_node_index += 1;
        }
    }
    
    return found_leaf.map(|leaf| {form_action_sequence(leaf, old_nodes_arena.into_vec())});
}

/// Restore the sequence of actions that was used to get to this node by climbing the tree of expanded nodes
fn form_action_sequence<A, T: SearchTreeState<A> + Hash>(
    leaf: HucsNode<A, T>,
    mut older_nodes: Vec<HucsNode<A, T>>,
) -> Vec<A> {

    let mut action_vector = Vec::new() as Vec<A>;
    
    let mut current = leaf;
    
    while let Some(action) = current.action {
        action_vector.insert(0, action);
        
        // Safe to swap as nodes' parents are always before them
        current = older_nodes.swap_remove(current.parent_index);
    }

    return action_vector;
}
```

I used the following program to test the algorithm, where `AddGame` tries to find the smallest combination of the given summands that add up to the goal (in a rather simple way).

### main.rs

```
extern crate hucs;

use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::time::Instant;

use hucs::{hucs, SearchTreeState};

fn main() {

    // Search that should fail
    run_game(11);

    for i in 1_000_000..1_000_020 {
        run_game(i);
    }
}

fn run_game(goal: u64) -> usize {

    let start = Instant::now();

    let game = AddGame::new(vec!(6, 16, 2017), goal);
    
    let predicate = game.make_predicate();
    let heuristic = game.make_heuristic();
    
    let count = match hucs(game, &*predicate, &*heuristic) {
        Some(solution) => solution.len(),
        None           => 0
    };
    
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    
    println!("{:>10}; {:>10}; {}.{:03}", goal, count, duration.as_secs(), duration.subsec_nanos() / 1000000);
    
    return count;
}

struct AddGame {
    summands: Vec<u64>,
    goal: u64,
    sum: u64,
}

/// AddGame is a basic test for the Uniform Cost Search where the combination
/// of the summands is wanted that has the least number of summands and adds up to
/// the given goal (a summand may be used multiple times)
impl AddGame {

    fn new(summands: Vec<u64>, goal: u64) -> Self {
        return AddGame {
            summands: summands,
            goal: goal,
            sum: 0,
        }
    }
    
    fn make_predicate(&self) -> Box<Fn(&AddGame) -> bool> {
        // Goal state is reached when the sum is exactly goal
        Box::new(move |game: &AddGame| game.sum == game.goal)
    }

    fn make_heuristic(&self) -> Box<Fn(&AddGame) -> f64> {
        // Heuristic score is remaining difference to goal divided by maximum summand
        let max_summand = self.summands.iter().cloned().max().unwrap();
        Box::new(move |game: &AddGame| (((game.goal - game.sum) / max_summand) as f64))
    }
}

impl Eq for AddGame {}

impl PartialEq for AddGame {
    fn eq(&self, other: &AddGame) -> bool {
        // Just compare by sum, used summands may differ
        // and goal should be equal if both trees originated
        // from the same root
        self.sum == other.sum
    }
}

impl Hash for AddGame
{
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher
    {
        // Just hash the state as only the state is relevant
        // for Eq
        self.sum.hash(state);
    }
}

impl SearchTreeState<u64> for AddGame {
    fn available_actions(&self) -> Vec<(u64, f64)> {
        let difference = self.goal - self.sum;
        
        return self.summands.iter()
            .cloned()
            // Do not exceed goal
            .filter(|s| *s <= difference)
            // Cost of applying an action is always 1 so we find minimum number of actions
            .map(|s| (s, 1.0))
            .collect();
    }
    
    fn apply_action(&self, act: &u64) -> Self {
        return AddGame {
            // Remove summands lower than the applied summands to order the action of adding summands,
            // otherwise have to go through a lot of different combinations of the same summand
            summands: self.summands.iter().cloned().filter(|s| *s >= *act).collect(),
            goal: self.goal,
            sum: self.sum + act
        }
    }
}
```

Since I am a complete beginner, I would be very interested in your feedback  regarding both the idiomaticness of the code and the performance, though I think the latter is already quite good.

I used typed-arena 1.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks pretty good! I can tell that you've paid attention to the  current Rust idiomatic formatting, which is nice to see. The code is also pretty short and readable.

### Overall

1. Write some tests!!11!1!!1 The code I show below compiles and I *think* it has the same results, but I don't know for sure.
2. Clippy has three classes of warnings for this code:

   1. `` warning: you seem to be trying to use match for destructuring a single pattern. Consider using `if let` ``

      Basically, you want to avoid this pattern

      ```
      match foo {
          One => interesting(),
          Two => {},
      }
      ```

      Instead, do

      ```
      if let One = foo {
          interesting();
      }
      ```
   2. `` warning: you should put `Foo` between ticks in the documentation ``

      This formats the documentation better.
   3. `warning: unneeded return statement`

      It's idiomatic to not have explicit returns.

### main.rs

1. Probably want to derive `Debug` for almost all types.
2. In many cases, can derive `Eq` instead of the manual impl.
3. Some of the closures don't need `move`.
4. Closures don't need a type on the closure argument; they can inferred.
5. Recommend calling `cloned` *after* the filter, that way you aren't cloning needlessly. In this case, cloning numbers should see no difference.
6. I might just dereference the `Copy` types in the closure argument to avoid the `cloned` call and any dereferencing in the bodies.
7. Can compare a reference to a value to another reference to a value (e.g. `&i32` with `&i32`), there's no need to dereference all the way to the value.
8. The pattern of

   ```
   match foo {
       Some(x) => x.bar(),
       None => default,
   }
   ```

   Can be replaced with `map_or`:

   ```
   let count = hucs(game, &*predicate, &*heuristic).map_or(0, |solution| solution.len());
   ```

```
extern crate hucs;

use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::time::Instant;

use hucs::{hucs, SearchTreeState};

fn main() {
    // Search that should fail
    run_game(11);

    for i in 1_000_000..1_000_020 {
        run_game(i);
    }
}

fn run_game(goal: u64) -> usize {
    let start = Instant::now();

    let game = AddGame::new(vec!(6, 16, 2017), goal);

    let predicate = game.make_predicate();
    let heuristic = game.make_heuristic();

    let count = hucs(game, &*predicate, &*heuristic).map_or(0, |solution| solution.len());

    let duration = start.elapsed();

    println!("{:>10}; {:>10}; {}.{:03}", goal, count, duration.as_secs(), duration.subsec_nanos() / 1000000);

    count
}

#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
struct AddGame {
    summands: Vec<u64>,
    goal: u64,
    sum: u64,
}

/// `AddGame` is a basic test for the Uniform Cost Search where the combination
/// of the summands is wanted that has the least number of summands and adds up to
/// the given goal (a summand may be used multiple times)
impl AddGame {
    fn new(summands: Vec<u64>, goal: u64) -> Self {
        AddGame {
            summands: summands,
            goal: goal,
            sum: 0,
        }
    }

    fn make_predicate(&self) -> Box<Fn(&AddGame) -> bool> {
        // Goal state is reached when the sum is exactly goal
        Box::new(|game| game.sum == game.goal)
    }

    fn make_heuristic(&self) -> Box<Fn(&AddGame) -> f64> {
        // Heuristic score is remaining difference to goal divided by maximum summand
        let max_summand = self.summands.iter().cloned().max().unwrap();
        Box::new(move |game| (((game.goal - game.sum) / max_summand) as f64))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for AddGame {
    fn eq(&self, other: &AddGame) -> bool {
        // Just compare by sum, used summands may differ
        // and goal should be equal if both trees originated
        // from the same root
        self.sum == other.sum
    }
}

impl Hash for AddGame {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher
    {
        // Just hash the state as only the state is relevant
        // for Eq
        self.sum.hash(state);
    }
}

impl SearchTreeState<u64> for AddGame {
    fn available_actions(&self) -> Vec<(u64, f64)> {
        let difference = self.goal - self.sum;

        self.summands.iter()
            // Do not exceed goal
            .filter(|&&s| s <= difference)
            // Cost of applying an action is always 1 so we find minimum number of actions
            .map(|&s| (s, 1.0))
            .collect()
    }

    fn apply_action(&self, act: &u64) -> Self {
        AddGame {
            // Remove summands lower than the applied summands to order the action of adding summands,
            // otherwise have to go through a lot of different combinations of the same summand
            summands: self.summands.iter().filter(|&s| s >= act).cloned().collect(),
            goal: self.goal,
            sum: self.sum + act
        }
    }
}
```

### lib.rs

1. Don't need `+ Hash` on every `T: SearchTreeState<A>` as that trait already has `Hash` as a supertrait.
2. Introduce a function on `HucsNode` to compute the total cost and use it in the `cmp` implementation. This avoids the value for `self` and `other` from diverging.
3. `BackedHashWrapper` can use derive all of the traits.
4. In fact, `BackedHashWrapper` doesn't provide any value; you can just store the reference in the hashmap directly.
5. I don't like the name `hucs`; would spell it out fully.
6. Why take a trait object reference (`&Fn(...)`) instead of a generic that implements the traits?
7. Why not combine the predicate and heuristic into a single trait; it seems like they are related and always together.
8. Naming a variable `hash_map` isn't descriptive. The type tells us that. Instead, describe what it's used for (instead of using a comment for that!)
9. In fact, you don't even need a hash map, a hash set will do, since you can get the cost from the key! Now the name is really bad ;-)
10. No need to specify `as usize`; type inference will take care of it.
11. Don't need the `'outer` loop label since you aren't breaking or continuiing out of nested loops. Just `break` and `continue` are fine.
12. No need for `as Vec<A>`; type inference handles it.
13. Inserting at the beginning vector seems inefficient, as it has to move everything down each insert, (O(N^2)). Instead, insert at the end and then reverse. (O(N))

```
extern crate typed_arena;

use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::{BinaryHeap, HashSet};
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

use typed_arena::Arena;

/// Extension of `SearchTree` that features action cost
pub trait SearchTreeState<A>: Eq + Hash {
    /// Get a list of available actions for this tree state and their corresponding costs
    fn available_actions(&self) -> Vec<(A, f64)>;

    /// Apply an action previously returned by available_actions
    /// and return the new search tree state
    fn apply_action(&self, act: &A) -> Self;
}

/// Node in the expanded search tree for uniform cost search with heuristic
#[derive(Debug)]
struct HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A>
{
    cost: f64,
    heuristic_cost: f64,
    parent_index: usize,
    action: Option<A>,
    tree: T,
}

impl<A, T> HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A>
{
    fn total_cost(&self) -> f64 {
        self.cost + self.heuristic_cost
    }
}

impl<A, T> PartialEq for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A>
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &HucsNode<A, T>) -> bool {
        // Nodes are equal if their tree states as this is what we are
        // interested in when comparing them in the map
        self.tree == other.tree
    }
}

impl<A, T> Eq for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A>
{
}

impl<A, T> Hash for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A>
{
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher
    {
        // Nodes are just hashed by their tree states since that also
        // defines their equality
        self.tree.hash(state);
    }
}

impl<A, T> PartialOrd for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A>
{
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &HucsNode<A, T>) -> Option<Ordering> {
        // Must never return None here as used by Ord
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl<A, T> Ord for HucsNode<A, T>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A>
{
    fn cmp(&self, other: &HucsNode<A, T>) -> Ordering {
        // Flip for min-heap, PartialOrd should never return None
        other.total_cost().partial_cmp(&self.total_cost()).unwrap()
    }
}

/// The initial capacity of both the arena of old nodes and the hash map of old nodes
const INITIAL_OLD_LIST_CAPACITY: usize = 1_000_000;

/// Perform a uniform cost search with a valid heuristic function on a search tree.
/// Returns a sequence of actions if a state is found that satisfies the predicate or
/// None if the search terminates beforehand.
pub fn hucs<A, T, P, H>(tree: T, predicate: P, heuristic: H) -> Option<Vec<A>>
where
    T: SearchTreeState<A>,
    P: Fn(&T) -> bool,
    H: Fn(&T) -> f64,
{
    // Min heap of the nodes in the expanded tree, ordered by actual cost to get to node
    // + heuristic cost to goal
    let mut open_list = BinaryHeap::new();

    // Push the initial node onto the tree
    open_list.push(HucsNode {
        action: None,
        // Parent index of root should never be read
        parent_index: usize::max_value(),
        cost: 0.0,
        heuristic_cost: heuristic(&tree),
        tree: tree,
    });

    let mut found_leaf = None;

    let old_nodes_arena = Arena::with_capacity(INITIAL_OLD_LIST_CAPACITY);

    // Destroy hash_map after this scope so items in the arena are no longer immutably borrowed
    {
        // Contains hashes and references to old_nodes_arena
        let mut hash_map: HashSet<&_> = HashSet::with_capacity(INITIAL_OLD_LIST_CAPACITY);
        let mut current_node_index = 0;

        while let Some(current_node) = open_list.pop() {
            if predicate(&current_node.tree) {
                found_leaf = Some(current_node);
                break;
            }

            // Check against the hash map
            if let Some(old_node) = hash_map.get(&current_node) {
                // Skip if we already had a better or equal path to this state with less cost
                if old_node.cost <= current_node.cost { continue; }
            }

            for (action, action_cost) in current_node.tree.available_actions() {
                let new_tree = current_node.tree.apply_action(&action);
                let new_cost = current_node.cost + action_cost;

                let new_node = HucsNode {
                    action: Some(action),
                    cost: new_cost,
                    parent_index: current_node_index,
                    heuristic_cost: heuristic(&new_tree),
                    tree: new_tree,
                };

                open_list.push(new_node);
            }

            // Add the current node to the arena of old nodes
            hash_map.insert(old_nodes_arena.alloc(current_node));

            current_node_index += 1;
        }
    }

    found_leaf.map(|leaf| form_action_sequence(leaf, old_nodes_arena.into_vec()))
}

/// Restore the sequence of actions that was used to get to this node by climbing the tree of expanded nodes
fn form_action_sequence<A, T: SearchTreeState<A>>(
    leaf: HucsNode<A, T>,
    mut older_nodes: Vec<HucsNode<A, T>>,
) -> Vec<A> {

    let mut action_vector = Vec::new();

    let mut current = leaf;

    while let Some(action) = current.action {
        action_vector.push(action);

        // Safe to swap as nodes' parents are always before them
        current = older_nodes.swap_remove(current.parent_index);
    }

    action_vector.reverse();

    action_vector
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I needed the wrapper because the HashMap takes ownership of the key, but I guess it can also take ownership of the reference then, right? I am a bit confused though, the HashSet holds `&_`, shouldnt `hash_set.get()` be called with a `Borrow<&_>` then which would be `&&_`, but here it is just called with `&_`

Comment: @MaxBenson yes, it needs to be called with something that implements `Borrow`, but there's a implementation for every type: `impl<T> Borrow<T> for T`. This means that, given a `T`, you can borrow a `&T` (which has some intuitive sense). Passing in a `&T` allows you to get a `&&T`.